# AngularJS ui-router optional parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I tried to set up my routing like this

```
...
url: '/view/:inboxId?'
...
```

but Angular would throw this error:

```
Error: Invalid parameter name '' in pattern '/view/:inboxId?'
```

so basically I had to set up two different states:

```
state('view', {
            url: '/view/:inboxId',
            templateUrl: 'templates/view.html',
            controller: 'viewCtrl'
        }).

        state('view_root', {
            url: '/view',
            templateUrl: 'templates/view.html',
            controller: 'viewCtrl'
        })
```

Is there any way to combine these states into one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To have an optional param - declare it as you did - but do not pass it. Here is an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/1fFsWiJEV89iEKoXzvqS?p=info). That all could work with one state *(no root)* or two *(root and detail)* as you like.

The definition mentioned in the question, is ready to handle these state calls:

```
// href
<a href="#/view/1">/view/1</a> - id is passed<br />
<a href="#/view/"> /view/ </a> - is is missing - OPTIONAL like <br />
<a href="#/view">  /view  </a> - url matching the view_root

// ui-sref
<a ui-sref="view({inboxId:2})">    - id is passed<br /> 
<a ui-sref="view">                 - is is missing - OPTIONAL like
<a ui-sref="view({inboxId:null})"> - id is explicit NULL <br />
<a ui-sref="view_root()">          - url matching the view_root
```

We do not have to use **`?`** to mark parameter as optional. Just both url must be unique (e.g. `/view/:id` vs `/view` - where the second does not have trailing `/`)

Comment: I think this will change with 0.3.0: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1476

Comment: I disagree with your statement - "That all could work with one state (no root)."  With a single state, the one with the parameter declared in the url, the "#/view" url would not match.  It would require a closing slash - "#/view/".  I would love for ui-router to support truly optional single parameters with one state, but it does not.  Even the newer "optional parameters" where you specify defaults in a params object require the closing slash before them.

Answer (score 3):

```js
.state('home', {
    url: '/home/:id/:token',
    templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
    controller: 'homeController',
    params: {
        id: { squash: true, value: null },
        token: { squash: true, value: null }
    }
})
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer.  Using "squash" makes the parameter optional and "value" allows you to set a default when the parameter is not supplied.

Answer (score 1):

The code below allows for truly optional parameters, if you don't mind having a couple extra states.

I turned my original state into an abstract one by adding the abstract attribute, and then created two children states, one with a url that has params, one with a blank url that references the parent.

It works well on my dev site, and doesn't require a trailing slash, in fact, if you want the trailing slash, you'll have to add a state/when for it.

```
  .state('myState.search', {
    url:'/search',
    templateUrl: urlRoot + 'components/search/search.view.html',
    controller: 'searchCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'search',
    abstract: true,
  })
  .state('myState.search.withParams', {
    url:'/:type/:field/:operator/:value',
    controller: 'searchCtrl',//copy controller so $stateParams receives the params
    controllerAs: 'search'
  })
  .state('myState.search.noParams', {
    url:''
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing, it really makes a difference when people add alternatives.  While a strict answer is correct, you never know other peoples use case.  Cheers!