# Angularjs UI-Router state params not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, state, angular-ui-router

I have a simple setup in my config()

```
    $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
          'url': '/app',
          'abstract': true,
          'templateUrl': 'views/layout/index.html',
          'controller': 'App'
        })

        .state('app.home', {
          'url': '/home',
          'views': {
            'appContent': {
              'templateUrl': 'views/home/index.html',
              'controller': 'Home'
            }
          }
        });
        .state('app.asd', {
          'url': '/asd/:idContact?',
          'views': {
            'appContent': {
              'templateUrl': 'views/asd/index.html',
              'controller': 'Asd'
            }
          }
        });
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home');
```

If i browse `app/asd/7` everything works if i browse then `app/asd` it redirects me

I am wondering how can i make idContact param not required ? I used the classic $routeProvider sintax for it :(

Comment: Lucky guess: does "app/asd/" with tailing slash work?

Comment: @jevgenig i get this error in console **Failed to instantiate module emotion due to:
Error: Invalid parameter name '' in pattern '/app/asd/:idContact?'**  cant understand whats wrong with it

Comment: The ":varName?" syntax seems to be not supported by stateProvider, but routerProvider. try regexp format: '/asd[/:idContact]'

Comment: @jevgenig i fixed it goind to kill myself it is all written in the doc i didnt noticed sorry, i am gonna close this question , thanks for support!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`/asd/{idContact:/?.*}`

As far as I know that is the workaround to make parameters optional in ui router. I'm not sure if there have been any recent built in implementations of this in ui router.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to provide some example giving the answer to optional parameter issue. See that all in [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/1fFsWiJEV89iEKoXzvqS?p=preview).

This Q&A does explain more details:

- [AngularJS ui-router optional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25476933/)

Here is a snippet of two states definition:

```
.state('view', {
    url: '/view/:inboxId',
    templateUrl: 'tpl.view.html',
    controller: 'viewCtrl'
}).

state('view_root', {
    url: '/view',
    templateUrl: 'tpl.view.html',
    controller: 'viewCtrl'
})
```

And here are some ways how to create links (`href` or `ui-sref`) to reach these states:

```
// href
<a href="#/view/1">/view/1</a> - id is passed<br />
<a href="#/view/"> /view/ </a> - is is missing - OPTIONAL like <br />
<a href="#/view">  /view  </a> - url matching the view_root

// ui-sref
<a ui-sref="view({inboxId:2})">    - id is passed<br /> 
<a ui-sref="view">                 - is is missing - OPTIONAL like
<a ui-sref="view({inboxId:null})"> - id is explicit NULL <br />
<a ui-sref="view_root()">          - url matching the view_root
```

That should show, that we do not have to pass some param, just must be sure that the proper url is called (the trailing `/`)

Comment: Great if that could help anyhow ;)

Comment: Not specifying parameter in `ui-sref` or setting it to null will cause controller to be invoked twice. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1476